# IONIC not receiving Socket data from server

Tags: angularjs, sockets, ionic-framework, meanjs

I am using ionic framework for my android app and MEANJS on my server. I am using Web Sockets to get realtime data. While the server side web application updates automatically every time a CRUD happens in the android application, the android app does not update automatically when a change is made on the server side.

**Android App Service**(AngularJS)

```
.service('Socket', ['Authentication', '$state', '$timeout',
function (Authentication, $state, $timeout) {
    // Connect to Socket.io server
    this.connect = function () {
      // Connect only when authenticated
      if (Authentication.user) {
        this.socket = io('https://cryptic-savannah-60962.herokuapp.com');
      }
    };
    this.connect();

// Wrap the Socket.io 'on' method
this.on = function (eventName, callback) {
  if (this.socket) {
    this.socket.on(eventName, function (data) {
      $timeout(function () {
        callback(data);
      });
    });
  }
};

// Wrap the Socket.io 'emit' method
this.emit = function (eventName, data) {
  if (this.socket) {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }
};

// Wrap the Socket.io 'removeListener' method
this.removeListener = function (eventName) {
  if (this.socket) {
    this.socket.removeListener(eventName);
  }
};
}
```

**Client Side Controller**

```
if (!Socket.socket && Authentication.user) {
  Socket.connect();
}

Socket.on('orderCreateError', function (response) {
  $scope.error = response.message;
});

Socket.on('orderCreateSuccess', function (response) {
  if ($scope.orders) {
    $scope.orders.unshift(response.data);
  }
});

Socket.on('orderUpdateSuccess', function (response) {
  if ($scope.orders) {
    // not the most elegant way to reload the data, but hey :)
    $scope.orders = Orders.query();
  }
});
```

**Server Controller**(NodeJS)

```
socket.on('orderUpdate', function (data) {
var user = socket.request.user;

// Find the Order to update
Order.findById(data._id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, order) {
  if (err) {
    // Emit an error response event
    io.sockets.emit('orderUpdateError', { data: data, message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
  } else if (!order) {
    // Emit an error response event
    io.sockets.emit('orderUpdateError', { data: data, message: 'No order with that identifier has been found' });
  } else {
    order.name = data.name;
    order.phone = data.phone;
    order.water = data.water;
    order.waiter = data.waiter;
    order.napkin = data.napkin;
    order.complete = data.complete;
    order.rating = data.rating;
    order.payment_mode = data.payment_mode;
    order.order_source = data.order_source;
    order.orderfood = data.orderfood;

    order.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        // Emit an error response event
        io.sockets.emit('orderUpdateError', { data: data, message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
      } else {
        // Emit a success response event
        io.sockets.emit('orderUpdateSuccess', { data: order, updatedBy: user.displayName, updatedAt: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(), message: 'Updated' });
      }
    });
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Does your client connect to socket server successful?

Comment: The client does not connect to the server. I believe I have a mistake or missing something in my code

Comment: have you tried changing `https://cryptic-savannah-60962.herokuapp.com` to `https://cryptic-savannah-60962.herokuapp.com:443`?

Comment: no i have not. i am new to this. would that help me to make my client work with socket

Comment: I experienced this several days ago with socket.io connection to Heroku. Can you try it and check browser console to make see if any error occurs?

Comment: Will try and update soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110246/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-vinay-and-heroandtn3).

Answer (score 1):

You have two emit channels on your server side but neither event is handled on the client side.

Per [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/), you need something like:

```
socket.on('orderUpdateSuccess', function (data) {
    // do something inside the app that will update the view
    console.log(data);
    Orders.update(data); // assuming you have a service called Orders to keep track of live data -- don't forget [$scope.$apply][2]
});
```

Using your example code

```
Socket.on('orderUpdateSuccess', function (response) {
    if ($scope.orders) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            // not the most elegant way to reload the data, but hey :)
            $scope.orders = Orders.query();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i have updated the Client Side Controller which is on my ionic side

Comment: Run your changes to the model inside of $scope.$apply. Right now the changes are not inside of AngularJS library code so they go unnoticed by the digest.

Comment: could show me as an updated answer to run changes to the model inside of $scope.$apply., i am new to this. thank you

Comment: In addition to using $scope.$apply, I would move the socket code to a service and use $broadcast to update Controllers. This way you don't need to open and close a socket continuously and the updated data will be available throughout the application.

Comment: socket io docs say i need to broadcast on the server side, do i have to do it on the client side as well?

Comment: Before we get into Angular's $broadcast, can you confirm that your client code is receiving socket data? Try to console.log some data.

If that works, try wrapping the code that updates order data in $scope.$apply so that the UI updates.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, i just verified, my client is not receiving socket data. how do i remedy it?

Comment: Are you testing in the browser or in a native app? Can you put your code in a Plunkr so I can test directly?

Comment: i tested in both browser and as an app

Comment: You have verified that your socket client is not receiving data. 2 possible reasons come to mind. 1) Your server is not emitting a message. You can debug your server code with a log file. 2) Your client is either not connected to the socket server or is not subscribed to the channel the server is emitting to. When looking in a browser, can you open Chrome Developer Tools and verify that the socket connection is successful? If so, when you look at the network message with a 101 response, you should be able to view the Frames property of that connection and see whether messages are inbound

Comment: Let me knows what I should do. Will try that

Comment: What you should do depends on the results of the tests above. What information are you getting from each test?